# How do we compute the `MPI_graph_create` index array?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

Can anyone use plain simple English to explain how `index` in function `MPI_Graph_create(MPI_Comm comm_old, int nnodes, const int index[],
            const int edges[], int reorder, MPI_Comm *comm_graph)`

I have been analyzing the `MPI_Graph_create` function as specified in the MPI man pages. I  miss the way `index[]` is computed. The standard specifies that `index` variable refers to the degree of the nodes which means a count of edges incident from the particular node . For the adjacency matrix below, the standard has  `index  = 2,  3,  4,  6` . I was expecting `2 , 1 ,1 ,2` based on the edges specified n the adjacency matrix.

```
Process  Neighbors
0         1,3
1         0
2         3
3         0,2
```

Correct answers from the MPI standard  are :-

```
nnodes = 4
index  = 2,  3,  4,  6 
edges  = 1 ,3, 0, 3,  0 ,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand it correctly, but are writing the indices incorrectly. That is, the "answer" `index= 2, 3, 4, 6` is identical to `index= 2, 1, 1, 2`.

Simply notice that

```
2 = 2
3 = 2 + 1
4 = 2 + 1 + 1
6 = 2 + 1 + 1 + 2
```

and you can see how your understanding of the problem matches up with the specification's answer. All you have to do is sum up your version in order to give `MPI_Graph_create()` the indices it wants.

Comment: Wow, thats a quite straight  and algorithmic , in short :-
`index [ i ] = incident_edges_at[ i ] + incident_edges_at[ i - 1 ]` for all i > 0, 
 else   `index [ i ] = incident_edges_at[ i ]`  , i.e.for  i==0

If I get you right?

Comment: I would write it algorithmically as `index[i] = sum( incident_edges_at[j], for all j <= i )`. But I think that's what you were getting at, so yes.